# How to cast string to object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, dereference, node-mongodb-native

I have this piece of code :

```
var regex={"$regex":req.query.query,"$options":req.query.options }  

db.collection('coders', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find(

    {"name":regex}

    ).toArray(function(err, items) {
    res.send(items);
    });

});
```

it works pretty well as expected. Now I want to be able to use arbitrary field instead of "name", so I tested this:

```
    var regex={"$regex":req.query.query,"$options":req.query.options }

    var field="\"notName\""

db.collection('coders', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find(

    {field:regex}

    ).toArray(function(err, items) {
    res.send(items);
    });

});
```

which does not work. What is the problem and what is correct way of invoking collection.find() with variables ?

Comment: `var condition = {}; condition[field] = regex; collection.find(condition)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to build the `find` argument object outside of the call using square bracket notation:

```
var toFind = {};
toFind[field] = regex;

db.collection('coders', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find(toFind).toArray(function(err, items) {
        res.send(items);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this variant

```
var regex={"$regex":req.query.query,"$options":req.query.options }
var field="notName";
db.collection('coders', function(err, collection) {
        var findExpression = {};
        findExpression[field]=regex;
        collection.find(findExpression).toArray(function(err, items) {
        res.send(items);
        });
});
```

Comment: That won't work. You're just creating an object literal with a key of "field", rather than the value of the `field` variable (the same as the OP).